# EXCEL 2010: COUNTIF using SUB-TOTAL (from filter) with multi criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Program:**  Excel 2010

I have a large selection of data which I filter for various reasons, I have been able to use the following to count my sales when filtered, however I want to be able add a 2nd criteria to the mix.

**New:**  count by value `B11` and `C12`
(B11) = Store Name
(C12) = Product Name

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$38:$C$1000=(B11)),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($C$38,ROW($C$38:$C$1000)-ROW($C$38),0)))
```

I have tried variations of the following however I keep getting errors:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$38:$C$1000=(B11),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($C$38,ROW($C$38:$C$1000)-ROW($C$38),0)),(--($C$38:$C$1000=(C12),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($C$38,ROW($C$38:$C$1000)-ROW($C$38),0)))  

|Prod    |Store
---------------
|ABC     |CDA
|DEF     |XYZ
|GHI     |TUV
|ABC     |XYZ  

Prod = ABC; Store = CDA; Result = 1  (not 2)
```

Please help :-)

Comment: You can't use a pivot table?

Comment: @Malk I probably should, but I haven't learnt about them, and I need to finish this EOM report today, so I'm going with what I know :), which is columns & countifs for now.

Comment: Your current formula is calculating the number of stores `CDA` right? And now you want to count the number of stores that are `CDA` and have product `ABC`?

Comment: @Jerry yes, I need to count only when BOTH (B) & (C) are fulfilled, so in the case above, it will be 1.  Because it is in a `SUBTOTALED` filtered range I can't use a straight `COUNTIF`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with `SUBTOTAL`, but this seems to work fine:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$38:$C$1000=(B11)),--($B$38:$B$1000=(C12)),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($C$38,ROW($C$38:$C$1000)-ROW($C$38),0)))
```

I just added `--($B$38:$B$50=(C12))` neat the beginning between the two expressions in the `SUMPRODUCT`

Comment: Thank you for your help :D  Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Another option to simplify formulas is to introduce a helper column which indicates whether the row is visible or not, e.g. in `Z38` copied down

`=SUBTOTAL(3,B38)`

Now for your count with 2 criteria you can use COUNTIFS like this

`=COUNTIFS(C:C,B11,B:B,C12,Z:Z,1)`

Comment: thank you.  I had looked in to that, but I wasn't sure how it would work due to the overall setup of the page.  I am using a dropdown for products, then with INDEX/MATCH I match prod values ($Un Price, Currency per store etc) as I filter down the columns. I know it's the long way round, but I haven't gotten in to Pivots etc. Maybe one day ...  LOL